# Is it possible to Rename a work Item type in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible and if so how do I rename a work item type in Azure DevOps (VSTS)?
Essentially I just want to change the name "Bug" to "Defect".

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the name of "Bug" to another name because it's system work item type.

If you want to use "Defect" instead of "Bug" you can create a custom process template:

[image]

Add new work item type with name "Defect" (define all the fields like in Bug):

[image]

[image]

Disable the "Bug":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For an **On-premises XML process**, one can use Microsoft's tool [witadmin.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-wit?view=azure-devops-2022#rename-a-work-item-type) and the command **renamewitd**

It is installed with Visual Studio. The path depends on your version and edition:

*Microsoft Visual Studio\{Version}\{Edition}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\witadmin.exe*